# Is touching a woman's hand allowed when exchanging money?

Tags: halal-haram, work, men-women

This hadith which I found on [Islam QA](https://islamqa.info/en/21183) is:

> It was narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yassaar said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “For one of you to be stabbed in the head with an iron needle is better for him than that he should touch a woman who is not permissible for him.”
>
> Narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Kabeer, 486. Shaykh al-Albaani said in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 5045, that this hadeeth is saheeh.

According to this article, it is understood from the hadith that touching a woman in any way is haram.

My case is that when you buy something from a shop and the cashier is a woman, she gives you change and you put your hand out to receive it but when the woman gives it, she touches your hand.

Is this a sin or not?

Comment: Touch in that Hadith in that context could be argued to mean intercourse and not touch. For instance the same word is used in surat Maryam: قَالَتْ أَنَّىٰ يَكُونُ لِي غُلَامٌ وَلَمْ يَمْسَسْنِي بَشَرٌ وَلَمْ أَكُ بَغِيًّا

Comment: I know but the website I got it from is talking about the ruling in shaking non-mahram' Shand which is touchin it. Click on the link.

Comment: I understand that **they** intepret the word as "touch" in its literal form. I just said it's possible to interpret the word another way as shown in surat Maryam.

Comment: Consider this hadith: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/102

Comment: @Kilise - How could "No, by Allaah, the hand of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) never touched the hand of any woman, rather they would give their oath of allegiance with words only." be interpreted to mean not having intercourse with them?

Comment: @III-AK-III I said it could **mean intercourse in that hadith he was quoting in his question** not the hadith you quoted now. And the hadith you quoted is **no way proving** it to be forbidden to for instance shake hands. Anyway that is not relevant to his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer in accordance to the view you got the quote from. But basically, because the question is so based on the hadith you have quoted, from Tabarani, I could only comment on that.

According to this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39936/15201) to the question: "[What is meant by touch in this hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39935/15201)"

> is **that the hadith is clearly speaking about intercourse**, and not just touch in its most literal sense.

With this conclusion I can answer your question:

#### Is touching a woman's hand allowed when exchanging money?

So, generally, with the above conclusion we don't have anything that prove that touching a woman's hand is forbidden when receiving change for instance. The answer would be based on your intention. When she returns money, her intention is to give you money back, and your should be to receive them. If your intention is that you now have an opportunity to touch her hand (which I doubt anyone does), then it would be a sin because you do it out of lust.

**References:**
[علي جمعة - حكم مصافحة المراة](https://youtu.be/oBQGKvueTCg?t=6m1s) - [Ali Gomaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_Gomaa)
Also relevant: [لماذا تُحَرّمون مصافحة النساء؟](http://www.hespress.com/opinions/247517.html)